# Get framebased timecode from receiver (Chromecast)

Tags: google-cast

is it at all possible to let the sender app know the exact time code (seconds AND frames!) of the video being played by the receiver? I could not find a native method for doing so but maybe someone knows something or managed to create a proprietary function for this?
Thanks!

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The Cast SDK does send regular media status updates to the sender. This is typically once per second. Frame level or time code accuracy isn't supported by the SDK.